# Why I got error when I divide doubles values?

Tags: c#

I am using windows forms. I have a button and 3 textboxes and I am trying to divide double numbers.

why when I enter 0 into textbox1 and 0 into textbox2 and when click button the result = NaN (Not a Number) value (it should be 0)? .When I enter differnt numbers it works well but when I enter 0 in texstbox1 and 0 in textbox2 then the result = NaN .

I just want to display 0 or 0.00 value in textbox3 as result of the division process when I divide 0 by 0.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double a, b, result;

    a = Convert.ToDouble( textBox1.Text );
    b= Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);

    result = a / b;     // I tried: result = (a / b) but the results still NaN;

    textBox3.Text = result.ToString();  // I tried: textBox3.Text = result.ToString("0:00") but the results still NaN;
}
```

Comment: 0/0 is an indetermined form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division by zero is not allowed, that's just math. To avoid an exception, you have two options.

Either test the second value to see if it's zero before performing the division:

```
result = (b != 0) ? (a / b) : 0;
```

Or catch the exception that'll be thrown:

```
try
{
    result = a / b;
}
catch (DivideByZeroException)
{
    result = 0;
}
```

Comment: division by zero would be `double.PositiveInfinity` or `NegativeInfinity` depending on dividend ;)

Answer (score 2):

Zero divided by zero is not defined. This is a basic mathematical property.

In all programming situations where you may encounter the expression "x / 0", you need to check before you attempt the division if the denominator is zero.

One solution is to use the following code to catch the error and display an error message:

```
if (b == 0)
    textBox3.Text = "Error, cannot divide by zero";
else {
    result = a / b;
    textBox3.Text = result.ToString();
}
```